# Class 'App\models\Test' not found when try to access model

Tags: php, laravel

I am try to learn laravel framework.

when i am try to use model at that time i got some error.

In my test controller

```
 <?php 
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;

        use App\models\Test;

        class TestController extends Controller {

            public function __construct()
            {
                $this->middleware('guest');
            }

            public function editData($id) {
                $result = DB::select('select * from users where id = ?', array($id));
                $data['data'] = $result[0];
                return view('myview', $data);
            }

       }
?>
```

and in my model

model path is app/models/Test.php

model name is Test.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Test extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';
    public static function getMyData(){

         $user = Test::find();

    }
}
?>
```

Output :

```
FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 56:
Class 'App\models\Test' not found
```

I am also try this command.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

But is not working.

Comment: You forgot to add a namespace to your `Test` class

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `Test` model isn't in any namespace at all. You would need to reference it by:

```
use Test;
```

or:

```
\Test::getMyData();
```

Or just put it in the namespace you try to reference it now:

```
<?php
namespace App\models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Test extends Model {
    protected $table = 'users';
    public static function getMyData(){
        $user = Test::find();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the model, write the below code,

```
namespace App\models;
```

This would work , only missing namespace in your code, rest all code is perfect

Answer (score 2):

you have imported your model wrongly
'm' of models is small

```
use App\models\Test;
```

this is the correct way:

```
use App\Models\Test;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The given question does not contain any class `Test` in the namespaces `App\models` or `App\Models`

Comment: That was helped me! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

modify config in vendor/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/config/ide-helper.php

```
'model_locations' => array(
    'app\Models',    //your models' location
),
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

$ModelName = new \App\Models\ModelName();

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The given code does not contain any class named `ModelName`